# Как передать именованный аргумент sqlite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Не могу разобраться, как мне передать именованный аргумент (переменную) в базу данных.

Создал базу данных следующим образом:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE users (id numeric)") #пробовал и текстовое значение
```

Пытался вставить переменную так:

```py
ids = [] #заполненный список с значениями, которые мне нужно вставить
for i in ids:
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,)", i) #пробовал через форматирование строки, тоже не вышло
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cursor.execute(sql, parameters)` в качестве параметров ожидает итерируемый объект (обычно список или кортеж):

```
ids = [1,2,3]

for i in ids:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?)", (i,))   # qmark style
#  NOTE: ---------------------------->       ^^^   ^^^^
```

---

используем *именованные* параметры:

```
for i in ids:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (:id)", {"id": i})  # (named style)
```

---

**ВНИМАНИЕ:** `(<скаляр>)` - *не является* кортежем!

```
In [55]: i = 1

In [56]: type( i )
Out[56]: int

In [57]: type( (i) )   #  /  NOTE!
Out[57]: int           #  \  (i) - это просто скаляр, а не кортеж

In [58]: type( (i,) )
Out[58]: tuple
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибку выдавать перестала, но база данных остается пустой, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, забыли сделать `conn.commit()` ?

Comment: да, спасибо большое, очень помогли!